# Binary cross entropy Keras -- how does it aggregate?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've been recently working with binary cross-entropy loss in Keras.

According to [enter link description here](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loss_functions.html), the loss is defined as:

```
−(ylog(p)+(1−y)log(1−p))
```

Yet I am wondering how the loss gets aggregated on the batch level. Is it summed, or averaged?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Averaged. Let's have a look:

```
labels = tf.constant([0,1,0], dtype=tf.float32)
predictions = tf.constant([0.5,1.0,0.0], dtype=tf.float32)
sess = tf.Session()
loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true=labels, y_pred=predictions)
print(sess.run(loss))
# 0.23104914
print(loss)
# Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Additionally:

```
loss = tf.keras.backend.binary_crossentropy(target=labels, output=predictions)
print(np.mean(sess.run(loss)))
# 0.23104914
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a very nice demonstration.